# making turtles move to gis points

Tags: gis, netlogo

so im making a netlogo project using GIS shape files.

i have a big point layer that represent places in a city like restaurants and gas stations.

i need my turtles to go in the direction of the points for example:
turtle pops at the housing area go to a random restaurant,
heads to the nearst gas station and comes back home.

i found "foreach (gis:property-value ?)" that runs on the table and made the points scale by color and objectID to ensure it works.
so now i can run on the column and the value but i dont know how to make a turtle move forward to the specific point. can i make it change its heading in the points direction or its direction to the patch the points sits on?

the project im mkaing is a 24 hour simulation that shows population movement in 7 city districts.

i have a polygon/vector layers dividing the city and i want to make turtles from certain districts to not be able to leave them unless a special action happens.
is there a way to make specific turtles stay in the polygon/vector lines?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure if this is the best way to do it, but I would probably approach this question by creating turtles at each of the places you want to be represented. I'd probably do it as a single breed and just have an attribute that says what type of place it is. You can hide the turtles so they are not visible on the interface.

The advantage of this approach is that then you can use all the native NetLogo primitives to do things like find a random restaurant within some radius and move towards it, instead of having to convert to the GIS layer. That is, you would only need to deal with GIS once (to create the turtles), which should deliver significant efficiency benefits.

Comment: first thank you for answering net logo is a new territory for me and this is my first project .
i made a code that tells my turtles to go to the nearest patch in the color i want. now the plan is making every set of specific buildings and places different colors so that the will have a kind of schedule and adding a random factor.
thing is that my gis layer includes more then 120k polygons and about 18k points so patches are about 5 km or even more so i need to solve it to a more realistic patch size.
any idea on how to make my points create patches?
if i have an x and y columns in my table

Comment: Points can't create patches. Patches already exist when you open the model, they are never created or destroyed. But you can certainly change the number of them by changing the world size.

Comment: trying this approach is there a way  to convert points to turtles or make the turtles in the right x,y  easily? i have a shp files with an x column and a y column

Comment: yes - look at the Model Library in NetLogo, open the GIS General Examples model. I think that the `city-labels` breed is essentially what you are trying to do.