# How to convert an xy exce or a shp.filel tables to turtles without writing the code

Tags: netlogo

I have a big table with more than 100k x and y values (in different columns) I want to create a turtle in each xy without writing the code with a new x and y values myself. Is there a better way to do it?

I tried entering the gis shp and I can see all the points and color by values them but I need my turtles to go to specific points and return x, y and the patches cover a lot of points so I can't color them as they keep overlaping colors every time.

Is there a better solution than this? Can I tell my turtles to go to the nearest point in the "place" column with the value "gas station"?

or maybe the nearest yellow Point? (same place but color coded so I won't have to go through the table every time)

Comment: What do you mean by "without writing the code"- you don't want to manually enter the coordinates of each turtle? Also, can you clarify- do you want to create a turtle at each of the 100k points or do you want them by able to move to those points?

Comment: As I said in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46771767/making-turtles-move-to-gis-points, the city-labels breed of turtles in the GIS example in the NetLogo Model Library creates turtles at locations specified by GIS data. Try understanding that example and then doing the same with your GIS data to create hidden turtles that are 'gas station' and 'restaurant' and whatever else you want. Then you can tell your people turtles to go to the nearest gas station.

Comment: no I do not want to enter the coordinates  manually. the only thing i need is for my turtles to be able to move to those points, im currently trying to put turtles (a breed for places) so my other turtles could move to their xy.  
if theres a better or easier way id like to know this is my first project.
@LukeC